# HERE Isoline Traffic:Disabled - How are routes calulcated

Tags: here-api

I'm experimenting with the Isoline API and have a question about the effects of two parameters:

- Mode: Shortest

  - The docs imply that things like turns are penalized.  By what factor? Known travel times, or some arbitrary estimation?
- Traffic: Disabled

  - The docs imply that traffic is not taken into account.  Does this mean the cost of traversing a component of a road is a function of the speed limit, or collected data on actual travel speeds on that route?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your questions:

- Turns are penalization depend on multiple factors which are different for turns of different characteristic (road types, turn geometry etc).
- This takes the actual travel speeds into account.